# There is no boxing conversion from "int" to 'T'

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, cycle

I have a generic method:

```
public JobKey Queue<TRequest>(TRequest request) where TRequest : IJobRequest{}
```

The IJobRequest:

```
 public interface IJobRequest
    {

    }
```

Next, in `foreach` cycle I want to call  `Queue<>()` generic method:

```
foreach (var item in campaigns)
                {
                    _jobScheduler.Queue<>();
                }
```

The 'item' variable is of my custom type 'Campaign' and has a property `int Id`

In `foreach` cycle I want to pass `item.Id` like parameter to `Queue<>()` method.

```
_jobScheduler.Queue<int>(item.Id);
```

What should I change in `interface IJobRequest` to be able to do like that: `_jobScheduler.Queue<int>(item.Id);` Because now I have an error: "There is no boxing conversion from "int" to 'IJobRequest'"

Comment: The answer is exactly what it says. You specify that a parameter has to implement `IJobRequest`. `int` does not implement `IJobRequest`. The easiest fix would be to change the line to `public JobKey Queue<TRequest>(int id) where TRequest : IJobRequest{}`

Comment: @DavidStockinger: I agree with what you say though at that point the Generic parameter can be removed entirely which leads us all to wonder what it is doing there in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

You have the constraint `TRequest : IJobRequest` which means that the type parameter should be inheriting/implementing the interface `IJobRequest` and clearly `int` type does not inherit form that interface.

What you need is to create a type which inherits from that interface and then you can use that one as argument in your method call.

Just as an example to demonstrate it would be something like:

```
public class MyType : IJobRequest
{

}
```

and then :

```
 MyType instance = new MyType();
_jobScheduler.Queue<MyType>(instance);
```

you will also need to apply [`new()` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) on type parameter to allow use of types with parameter-less constructor.

or alternatively you can remove that contraint on generic parameter :

```
public JobKey Queue<TRequest>(TRequest request)
```

Hope it gives you idea.